# Resize element to include or exclude neighboring text - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm trying to figure out how to create an element which can be resized to contain more or less of the surrounding text.

This might not be on the right track but I have a codepen here, https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GvWpmV, with a resizable div in a blue background. When the div gets dragged to the right it pushes the text over. What I need to happen is for the text to stay in place but now be surrounded by the blue div. The reverse should happen when shrinking the div. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<html lang = "en">
   <head>
      <meta charset = "utf-8">
      <title>Drag element test</title>
      <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
         rel = "stylesheet">
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

      <!-- CSS -->
      <style>
         .ui-widget-header {
            background:#b9cd6d;
            border: 1px solid #b9cd6d;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-weight: bold;
         }
         .ui-widget-content {
            background: #cedc98;
            border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
            color: #333333;
         }

        #blue-div {background-color: blue;
         display: inline-block;

         }
      </style>

      <!-- Javascript -->
      <script>
         $(function() {
            $( "#blue-div" ).resizable({ghost: true});
         });
      </script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <!-- HTML --> 
      <div id="main"> 
         There is some text here. I would like to change the text in the blue div.
         <div id="blue-div" class="ui-widget-content">blue</div> 
      more words here.
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Edited to add:**
The end product has a block of text on the page with short sections wrapped in a custom element, which changes the appearance. When a user clicks on an element a jquery event fires, which highlights the area and opens a form. The user can edit or delete the information relating to the custom element.

What I need to add is the ability for the user to drag the custom element to include more or less of the surrounding text. For example a user can click on the element and then resize it so that the html changes from

```
This <el>is</el> a test
```

to

```
This <el>is a</el> test
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the blue `<div>` a `position: absolute` and a `z-index` value higher than the text.

```
#blue-div {
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 99;
    position: absolute;
}
#main {
    z-index: 98;
    position: relative;
}
```

Also, I'm not sure why your CSS is inline?

Comment: Thanks, that keeps the text from being moved but it doesn't move the newly covered text into the blue div. Is there any way to stretch the div so that it now includes the extra text?

Comment: Oh and the CSS is inline because I copied the example from the resizable docs to make a quick example. That's how it is there.

Comment: I would need to know a bit more about the context of what you're trying to achieve. There are a few ways to accomplish this, I just don't know how it will be used.

Comment: Ok, I edited the original post to add an example and more information about the end goal.